# query Fetch data from multiple tables MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, radio-button

i have a page on which there is a form, in which there are two radio buttons, on selected the on of the related buttons, it's related content will be shown on the form.

```
<tr class="text">
<td colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="f2f2f2">
<?php
$srl=mysql_query("select * from module ORDER BY module_id ASC");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($srl))
{ ?>
<input type="radio" name="module" value=<?php echo $rows[module_id] ?>><?php echo $rows[module_name] ?>
<?php
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<tr class="text">
<td colspan="6">
<div id="items_list"></div>
</tr>
```

and i have write this jquery for api calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                $("module").change(function() {
                var module_id = $(this);
                var dataString = 'module_id='+  module_id.val();
                alert(dataString);
                $("#items_list").html("");
                if(module_id.val()=='')
                  {
                     alert("select stock type");
                   }
                else {
                                $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "ajax/request_fetch_items.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(){
                                    $("#items_list").html( html );
                                },
                                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                        //On error, we alert user
                                            alert(thrownError);
                                            }
                                });
                }
                return false;
                });
                });
                </script>
```

but nothing happens when i select any radio button, neither it shows the alert in jquery.
what i want is whenever a radio button is selected, its value is passed via ajax call, the the remaining html content will be load into the next row.

On inepcting the radio buttons it shows following code,

```
<input type="radio" name="module" value="1">Stationary  
<input type="radio" name="module" value="2">Inventory
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` is showing on the console.

Comment: i'm not sure that HTML part with radio button is good, with the console inspect html of radio buttons and paste

Comment: @MuhammadTaqiHassanBukhari that error seems self-explanatory.

Comment: I have solve the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` error in the console, no there is not error and warning in the console. but still not call is not made, neither the alert.

Comment: you have not written "If" statement for "else"!!

Comment: @LucaOlivieri and others i have updated the question please review it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery selector `$("module")` is targeting `<module>` html tags, just change it to `$("input[name=module]:radio")` so it targets `<input>` elements of type radio named module.

https://jsfiddle.net/eh6c5wjb/